# Facebook log in supplies data but does not ask for any permissions whatsoever

Tags: ajax, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I recently implemented the Facebook log-in on a site which I've been working on. I need to pull some data from the user and call the following function when the user clicks the 'log in' button

```
  function authUser() {
    FB.login(checkLoginStatus, {scope:'user_likes,user_status,user_birthday'});
  }
```

The user gets logged in alright and I can pull 'user_likes,user_status,user_birthday', however the dialog never asks for any of the above permissions.

I've also tried 'perms' in place of 'scope' as reference in similar stack overflow question.

For what it's worth, here's my FB.init()

```
  FB.init({
    appId: 'my id',
    xfbml: true,
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
  });
```

Any ideas on why permissions are not being asked for?

Comment: Have you for once did provide these permissions for your app? If yes then it wouldn't ask again. If you want to check, then unauthorize the app and retry. Additionally you may also check if you have those permissions or not at `/userID/permissions` end point

Answer (score 0):

If you have authorized the app for once with the required permissions, you or any other user will not get the additional pop up for allowing or denying the access for the additional permission. To check if you have authorized the app with the required permissions you can check with the result from the following end point

```
/userID/permissions
```